# xamarin mac app vsts build definition

Tags: azure-pipelines, xamarin.mac

Has anyone tried to build Xamarin.Mac app using VSTS build definition?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Could someone tell me which build task to use to build the xamarin.mac project?

Comment: Do you mean the app is develop on Xamarin studio on mac OS? If it is, you should queue your build on a private agent in mac OS.

Comment: Nope. The project is a Xamarin.Mac project and it is a Mac desktop app. In VSTS there are templates to build the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects. But there is none for Xamarin.Mac apps. Currently, I am Using an MSBuild engine to build the project but need to know how the app can be signed using the certificate. I could not find an example online. Yes we have a private Mac Build agent configured to our vsts build server.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin.mac app you can directly use **visual studio build task**. And it’s unnecessary to use xamarin license. So you can use below tasks:

- [NuGet Instller](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer)
- [Visual studio build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build)
- [Copy Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files)
- [Publish build artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts)

For the build agent: you can use hosted agent or private agent which install visual studio (no matter on mac OS or windows OS).

[image][image]

And there only have Xamarin.android and Xamarin.iso templates this is because they are mobile app and has some different between platform app. If you want add a template for Xamarin.mac, you can save your build definition as template.

[image]

**Note:** Since you want to generate `.app` for mac not `.exe` for windows, you should use the agent on mac, and also check if VS is in agent capabilities. If not, you should add VS in it.

[image]